# Why is computer slow in switching between opened applications?

Tags: hard-drive, google-chrome, windows-8.1, memory, performance

I like to open a lot of Chrome tabs, but when I try to switch between open tabs, the tab tends to re-render. When I have some other applications open alongside with chrome, those applications also tend to do that. Re-rendering sometimes takes as long as 20 seconds, which is quite annoying.

My computer also tends to freeze up for a few minutes after a wake up from hibernation or sleep. After few hours of use, every open application also goes not responding together, and only goes back after a few minutes. Explorer normally restarts when that happens.

I have 16GB of memory available and when I check my task manager when such thing happens, there are still 8GB of memory that is free. However there is normally 100% disk access.

System: Windows 8.1 Pro
CPU: Intel Core i7-4500U
Memory: DDR3 SODIMM 2*8GB
HDD: WD 1TB

So why isn't my computer keeping open applications in the memory? Will swapping to an SSD help?

Aha...resources for answering this question:
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-superfetch-prefetch-ssd
https://serverfault.com/questions/419048/system-process-pid-4-constantly-accessing-the-hard-disk